# .NET: What does Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled do?

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

It is [not well known](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bttkazd%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), that if you draw an image, e.g.:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, top, left);
```

the image will be scaled. This is because [`DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536030%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) looks at the dpi setting of the image (e.g. 72dpi from photoshop), and scales the image to match the destination display (typically 96dpi).

If you want to draw an image without any scaling, you must explicitly give `DrawImage` the size of the image:

```
graphics.DrawImage(img, top, left, img.Width, img.Height);
```

i knew this from years of programming in GDI+. The same fact exists in the .NET `System.Drawing` wrappers around GDI+ - if you want to draw an image unscaled you must force it to scale to the original size.

Which is why i was impressed to find a `DrawImageUnscaled` method in .NET:

```
graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, top, left);
```

Except that the image is still scaled; making it identical to:

```
graphics.DrawImage(img, top, left);
```

and if you want to draw an image unscaled you must continue to call:

```
graphics.DrawImage(img, top, left, img.Width, img.Height);
```

Which brings me to my question: what does `DrawImageUnscaled` if not to draw an image unscaled?

### From MSDN

- [**Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled Method (Image, Int32, Int32)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0tzkb5.aspx)

  > Draws the specified image using its original physical size at the location specified by a coordinate pair.
- [**Graphics.DrawImage Method (Image, Int32, Int32)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/558kfzex.aspx)

  > Draws the specified image, using its original physical size, at the location specified by a coordinate pair.
- [Graphics.DrawImage Method (Image, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsak4dc.aspx)

  > Draws the specified Image at the specified location and with the specified size.

### See also

- [MSDN: How to: Improve Performance by Avoiding Automatic Scaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bttkazd%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956965/c-sharp-resize-image-canvas-keeping-original-pixel-dimensions-of-source-image/5957023#5957023)

Comment: @LarsTech As per that answer: `DrawImage` *also* scales the image - unless you force the size it draws to be identical to the source image's size. So the statement, *"Use the DrawImage method instead to draw the image using the original pixel size"* is misleading. One might come away from that thinking that `DrawImage` draws an image at the original pixel size.

Comment: This [thread](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/22/112811.aspx) talks about DrawImageUnscaled was equivalent to BitBlt and DrawImage was equivalent to ScaleBlt, but I'm guessing he meant StretchBlt.

Comment: See also MSDN's [KB317174](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=317174).

Comment: _If you want to draw an image without any scaling, you must explicitly give DrawImage the size of the image_ - __Not true__!. To avoid dpi related scaling simply adapt the image's dpi to the current screen dpi before drawing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled Method (Image, Int32, Int32)` doesn't do anything different than `DrawImage (Image, Int32, Int32)`

e.g.

```
public void DrawImageUnscaled(Image image, int x, int y)
{
    this.DrawImage(image, x, y);
}
```

However the methods that take in a Height, Width or a rectangle are different. Those methods either ignore the height and width or with the rectangle only use the top and left.

My guess is that `DrawImageUnscaled Method (Image, Int32, Int32)` exists for parity reasons and doesn't have to do with scaling due to dpi difference in the source and target device.