# Why is this code shrinking my image?

Tags: asp.net, image, system.drawing

I've take some code and reduced it down to a few lines which still reproduce the error i am having. In this case, I am taking an image that is 448x298 in size and trying to overlay it on top of a white background that's 600x450.

So I'm expecting to get an image that's 600x450 with a white background and my original image laid on top of it starting in the upper right corner. And i expect my original image to remain it's original size. Instead the original image is going from 448x298 to approximately (give or take a pixel or two) 143x95

Here is the reduced code that's doing this:

```
                System.Drawing.Image oImage = new Bitmap(600, 450);
                Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oImage);
                oGraphic.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 600, 450);
                oGraphic.DrawImage(image, new Point(0,0));
                return (Bitmap)oImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the target size. The [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/42807xh1.aspx) you chose scales the image from the source dpi to the target dpi. As explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8072003/11963), you should do this:

```
System.Drawing.Image oImage = new Bitmap(600, 450);
Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oImage);
oGraphic.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 600, 450);
oGraphic.DrawImage(image, 0,0, image.Width, image.Height);
return (Bitmap)oImage;
```