# C# user control scaling image wrongly

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a usercontrol with an Image property. The image is the resources.resx and has a size of 48x48.

When I draw the image on the control using:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
//or
e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
```

The image is always scaled to about 1.5 times its size. The only way to keep the image the size I want it is to pass a Rectangle to the methods.

Why is the usercontrol/image behaving like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say the image is scaled I suppose you are referring to its number of pixels...

But DrawImage use the device resolution to maintain its "physical size".

See this from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/558kfzex(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The DrawImage method draws an image using its physical size, so the
>   image will have its correct size in inches regardless of the
>   resolution (dots per inch) of the display device. For example, suppose
>   an image has a pixel width of 216 and a horizontal resolution of 72
>   dots per inch. If you call DrawImage to draw that image on a device
>   **that has a resolution of 96 dots per inch, the pixel width of the
>   rendered image will be (216/72)*96 = 288**.

...so this is the reason of the function behavior.

The [same applies to DrawImageUnscaled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8072160/19046).

Comment: The image has a dpi of 72 and it's still being scaled.

Comment: So you need to know your device "Dpi"... I'm not sure, but it seems you can get it using [Graphics.DpiX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpix(v=vs.110).aspx)