# Simpler way of drawing an image with pixels as the unit

Tags: c#, winforms, drawimage

I am trying to get the handle on some C# functions. Is there any simpler way to draw an image to the screen in Windows Forms using pixels as the measurement ? I just want that accuracy, as I am going to eventually run through an array of a World Level and put grass and walls etc on the screen based on the array.

```
        Image grass = Bitmap.FromFile("grass.png");

        // Create parallelogram for drawing image.
        Point ulCorner = new Point(0, 0);
        Point urCorner = new Point(100, 0);
        Point llCorner = new Point(0, 100);
        Point[] destPara = { ulCorner, urCorner, llCorner };

        // Create rectangle for source image.
        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

        // Draw image to screen.
        GFX.DrawImage(grass, destPara, srcRect, units);
```

I know I can do the following:

```
GFX.DrawImage(grass, new point(50,50) );
```

But the problem is this is now not using pixels as the measurement so I cannot position it correctly on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `DrawImage` but specifying the width and height you want, otherwise GDI+ will take into account the DPI of the device and scale it.

```
graphics.DrawImage(grass, top, left, grass.Width, grass.Height);
```

Beware `DrawImageUnscaled()`, contrary to what it suggests, will actually continue to scale.

> *Well Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled Method (Image, Int32, Int32) doesn't do anything different than DrawImage (Image, Int32, Int32)* -  [Tell me more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072003/net-what-does-graphics-drawimageunscaled-do)

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. I knew there had to be a way. It just didn't seem simple enough.