# Is there a benefit to using Graphics.DrawImage(Image, RectangleF destRect, RectangleF srcRect, GraphicsUnit srcUnit) when the image is a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, graphics, drawimage

Unless I miss something bitmaps are quantized (pixel-oriented). So what happens when someone tries the following:

```
   public void Foo(Bitmap image)
   {
        var destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
        var resultingSubimage = new Bitmap(destinationRect.Width, destinationRect.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resultingSubimage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationRect, new RectangleF(30.3245F /*x*/, 23.234234F /*y*/, 50F, 50F), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            // vs graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationRect, new Rectangle(30 /*x*/, 23 /*y*/, 50, 50), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
   }
```

notice that the x and y fields are decimals which point to a sub-pixel point. But is there even such a thing as a sub-pixel point for bitmaps? What's going on under the hood? Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but the online documentation for both Graphics.DrawImage() and for the underlying p/invoke function 'GdipDrawImageRectRect' do not shed any light in this.

Comment: In a paranoid world, you could implement that with subpixel cropping in the destination (implying a blend with the visible part of the underlying pixel), and subpixel resampling in the source, which could just be subpixel translation. My guess is that the overload is just there for uniformity/convenience of the API, and the coordinates are rounded. You can test that.

Comment: This code cannot compile, there is no such overload.  That is not beneficial.  The overload that takes RectangleF arguments can be useful for a GraphicsUnit *other* than Pixel.  The way the bitmap edges look depend on the Graphics.InterpolationMode and PixelOffsetMode properties.

Comment: I put together this method under .net4.0. I apologize for not mentioning this in the original post. Which .net version have you tried it on mr. Passant?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did test the method with both flavours and the resulting cropped-images came out slightly different. I cowardly refrained from using the RectangleF flavour and resorted to pad the dimensions of the rectangle properly so that the eventual integer-rectangle encompasses the entire RectangleF. But the question at hand lingered on.

Comment: I think Hans is overlooking that there's an implicit conversion from `Rectangle` to `RectangleF`. The code you posted looks like it's passing a `Rectangle` to the method for the destination parameter, but of course what's really happening is your `Rectangle` is implicitly converted to `RectangleF` and you're using the overload that takes two `RectangleF` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "benefit". What overload would you use instead? I.e. "benefit" as compared to what?

It is most assuredly *not* the case that the overload is completely useless when dealing with `Bitmap` objects. Firstly, the `GraphicsUnit` value determines how the coordinates passed to the method are interpreted and of course one might pass something other than `GraphicsUnit.Pixel`. For example, suppose you are using `GraphicsUnit.Inch` and the resolution of the image is 120 dpi. Then each pixel is only 1/120th of an inch, and for per-pixel precision, your floating point values would be multiples of that (i.e. multiples of 0.0083333333333333), and not integer values.

Secondly, the `Graphics` object can be configured to do sub-pixel sampling in a variety of ways, and in such cases, a fractional pixel value could have meaning, even if the units being described were pixels.

You ask "what's going on under the hood", but I'm afraid that part is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. The `Graphics` object uses GDI+ as the underlying mechanism when using it on a Windows platform; the answer to what *specifically* happens with different configurations of the `Graphics` object would require a lengthy treatise.

If you want that level of detail, the right place to start would be the MSDN documentation for the GDI+ in the native Windows API. For most parts of `Graphics`, there's a one-for-one correspondence between the .NET API and the native one.

By the way, to be clear: your coordinates in this scenario are *`float`* values. I would be cautious about using the word "decimal" here, because .NET/C# has an actual `decimal` type, and you're definitely not using that. :)

Comment: 'cautios' is __so__ nice.. ;-)

Comment: <<What overload would you use instead? I.e. "benefit" as compared to what?>> You are absolutely right. I meant a benefit vs using the simple int-rectangle flavors.

Comment: I think I understand why the RectangleF overloads exist now. My curiosity has been sated ... for now at least. Thank you for the insights.

Answer (score 3):

It is [not well known](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bttkazd%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), that if you draw an image, e.g.:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, top, left);
```

the image will be scaled. This is because [`DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536030%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) looks at the dpi setting of the image (e.g. 72dpi from photoshop), and scales the image to match the destination display (typically 96dpi).

If you want to draw an image without any scaling, you must explicitly give `DrawImage` the size of the image:

```
graphics.DrawImage(img, top, left, img.Width, img.Height);
```

By calling, `DrawImage` **with** the the destination rectangle that matches the original image's pixel size, you are avoiding a resampling/rescaling.

**Bonus Reading**

- [.NET: What does Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072003/net-what-does-graphics-drawimageunscaled-do)

Comment: _the image will be scaled._ Let's make that _the image may be scaled._ Often the images have the same resolution..

Comment: Didn't know all this. Thanks for giving me a headsup.

Comment: @TaW the image will usually be scaled because, for example, Photoshop saves images with a dpi of 72 pixels per inch. Because Windows monitors are 96 pixels per inch, or higher, `DrawImage(img, x, y)` will scale the image up by 33%.

Comment: No. Images are __not__ usually created in Photshop and when I do I always control their dpi to suit my needs. Which certainly is never 72dpi. And no: Photoshop does not by default create 72dpi images. Instead it suggest the resolution you have set the last time. - But yes, it is important to keep that issue in mind!