# Difference between DrawImage and DrawImageUnscaled

Tags: .net

The documentation is not really clear to me.
Used in certain ways, DrawImage will do just the same as DrawImageUnscaled.
Why has DrawImageUnscaled been introduced?

Comment: It is a pretty odd design bug that defies a simple explanation.  Having DrawImageUnscaled in fact not rescale the image would have been pretty sensible.  But it doesn't, DrawImageUnscaled simply calls DrawImage(), visible in the [Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,2f0714b9077274ba).  So there is no point in using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET: What does Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072003/net-what-does-graphics-drawimageunscaled-do)